# Form in Facebook iFrame Tab: $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" returns TRUE

Tags: php, facebook, forms, tabs, request

so I've been creating a form that writes some information to a database. It should be integrated in a facebook tab. So far it works quite well, but I get some problems in checking for the form submission. I do it like that:

```
protected function isFormSubmission() {
   return ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST");
}
```

My whole form check works like that:

```
public function normForm() {
    if ($this->isFormSubmission()) {
        if ($this->isValidForm()) {
            $this->processForm();
        }
        else {
            $this->printForm();
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->printForm();
    }
}
```

My problem is that Facebook somehow returns TRUE for ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") immediately when the tab is loaded. This means that the function isValidForm() returns FALSE and all the user-input-errors are shown...
When I load the page independently from FB it works fine...

Here is the link to the page: https://ssl-account.com/sparfuchs.cash-back-info.com/sparfuchs_werden/index.php

Why does FB return TRUE for ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") and how can i avoid that?

Thanks a lot,

Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heh...  i don't really know why (maybe cache, structure, external app policy, whatever). To avoid this use some hidden input with token. Moreover it good to use some "anti-"CSRF ((not fully safe CSRF but its a some kind of solution against)

Comment: thanks my solution is: 
`protected function isFormSubmission($token) {
        return ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && isset($_SESSION[$token]) && !$this->isEmpty($token);
    }`